# SQL Oracle - sum values in columns in first table using column names that are stored as values (rows) in second table

Tags: sql, oracle

Table A

```
Store_Num   BKT1    BKT2    BKT3    BKT4    BKT5    BKT6    BKT7    BKT8    BKT9
111         1       2       1       0       3       2       4       2       5
```

Table B

```
Monthly_Bucket  Weekly_Buckets                                  
MBKT1           BKT3,BKT4,BKT5,BKT6                                 
MBKT2           BKT7,BKT8,BKT9,BKT10
```

Query should look in Table B.Monthly_Bucket columns corresponding values in Weekly_Buckets column. Then take the values from Weekly_Buckets column as column names to select and sum corresponding values in Table A
eg: In Table B Monthly_Bucket let's take value MBKT1, now we see that corresponding value of MBKT1 in Weekly_Buckets column is BKT3,BKT4,BKT5,BKT6.
So, we take this value BKT3,BKT4,BKT5,BKT6 and treat each value BKT3 and BKT4 and BKT5 and BKT6 separately as column names to select data and sum these 4 columns into one column from Table A. And result should look like below

Result Table

```
Store_Num   MBKT1                                   
111         6    (we got this by summing columns BKT3,BKT4,BKT5,BKT6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `like` operator and avoid the splitting of the `weekly_buckets` strings into components, like so:

```
with table_a (store_num, BKT1, BKT2, BKT3, BKT4, BKT5, BKT6, BKT7, BKT8, BKT9) as (
       select 111, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5 from dual
     ),
     table_b (monthly_bucket, weekly_buckets) as (
       select 'MBKT1', 'BKT3,BKT4,BKT5,BKT6'  from dual union all
       select 'MBKT2', 'BKT7,BKT8,BKT9,BKT10' from dual
     ),
     table_a_unpivot (store_num, weekly_bucket, weekly_value) as (
       select * from table_a 
       unpivot (
         weekly_value for 
               weekly_bucket in (BKT1, BKT2, BKT3, BKT4, BKT5, BKT6, BKT7, BKT8, BKT9) 
       )
     )
select a.store_num, monthly_bucket, sum(weekly_value) as monthly_value
from   table_a_unpivot a
join   table_b         b
       on b.weekly_buckets || ',' like '%' || a.weekly_bucket || ',%'
group by store_num, monthly_bucket;
```

Result:

```
 STORE_NUM MONTHLY_BUCKET MONTHLY_VALUE
---------- -------------- -------------
       111 MBKT1                      6
       111 MBKT2                     11

2 rows selected.
```

Notice the "terminating comma" in the join condition (second to last line of code); without that ugly trick, BKT1 will match BKT10 in the MBKT2 aggregate string, contrary to your requirement.

**Edit:**

To get monthly bucket values lined up in columns, you can use the `pivot` operation (assuming you know beforehand the names of the possible buckets), like so:

```
with table_a (store_num, BKT1, BKT2, BKT3, BKT4, BKT5, BKT6, BKT7, BKT8, BKT9) as (
       select 111, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5 from dual
     ),
     table_b (monthly_bucket, weekly_buckets) as (
       select 'MBKT1', 'BKT3,BKT4,BKT5,BKT6'  from dual union all
       select 'MBKT2', 'BKT7,BKT8,BKT9,BKT10' from dual
     ),
     table_a_unpivot (store_num, weekly_bucket, weekly_value) as (
       select * from table_a 
       unpivot (
         weekly_value for 
               weekly_bucket in (BKT1, BKT2, BKT3, BKT4, BKT5, BKT6, BKT7, BKT8, BKT9) 
       )
     ),
     m (store_num, monthly_bucket, weekly_value) as (
       select a.store_num, b.monthly_bucket, a.weekly_value
       from   table_a_unpivot a
       join   table_b         b
              on b.weekly_buckets || ',' like '%' || a.weekly_bucket || ',%'
     )
select * from m
pivot (sum(weekly_value) for monthly_bucket in ('MBKT1' as MBKT1, 'MBKT2' as MBKT2));
```

Result:

```
 STORE_NUM      MBKT1      MBKT2
---------- ---------- ----------
       111          6         11
```

Comment: Hey, this works fine but last thing i need is data in below format:                                  STORE_NUM     MBKT1     MBKT2                                                                                 111                      6               11

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't say so when you asked the question initially?

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding that may have caused by my question initially. But i think i had mentioned in my  question under "Result Table" the format which I am looking for.

Comment: Actually I take it back, you are right - you clearly wanted MBKT1 as the column header, not a value in the table. You can pivot the results (I will show how in a moment), but you need to know which MBKTx values will exist beforehand (otherwise you need dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a desing of your data structures needs a normalization.
You can try a query like this, but it will be probably very inefficient, you need to normalize data to get better results:

```
SELECT store_num, monthly_bucket, sum( some_value )
FROM (
    SELECT *
    from TABLEA
    UNPIVOT (
       some_value FOR col_name IN ( BKT1, BKT2, BKT3, BKT4, BKT5, BKT6, BKT7, BKT8, BKT9 )
    )
) a
JOIN (
  select monthly_bucket, trim(column_value) Weekly_Buckets
  from tableb, xmltable(('"' || replace(Weekly_Buckets, ',', '","') || '"'))
) b
ON b.Weekly_Buckets  = a.col_name
GROUP BY store_num, monthly_bucket

 STORE_NUM MONTH                         SUM(SOME_VALUE)
---------- ----- ---------------------------------------
       111 MBKT1                                       6
       111 MBKT2                                      11
```

Comment: I am trying to run   one of the select query from your solution above but get error: ORA-02000: missing COLUMNS keyword :                                         : select monthly_bucket, trim(column_value) Weekly_Buckets
  from tableb, xmltable(('"' || replace(Weekly_Buckets, ',', '","') || '"'))

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciate your help!